# Chrome 48 adds a scrollbar if border-radius [OSX]

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome

Recently I updated my Chrome to v48 and I came across a weird bug. So I've a pretty simple markup with a `<pre>` tag with some basic styles

```
pre {
  border: 1px solid #dedede;
  overflow: auto;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

Now the issue is, if I use `border-radius` for `pre` tag, Chrome forcefully shows horizontal scrollbar. If I remove the `border-radius` property, the horizontal bar will disappear and will reappear on scroll as expected.

[image: Scrollbar]

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/hk57e500/)

[**Demo 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/hk57e500/1/) *(Correct behavior but only if I remove `border-radius` [for mac users])*

Just to clarify that am on Mac OSX Yosemite, so scrollbars are not shown until you start scrolling (not sure if Windows does the same thing, am sure it doesn't).

> **Additional details:**
>   Mac Pro Retina
>   OS: OSX Yosemite <sup>v10.10.5</sup>
>   Chrome Ver: 48.0.2564.97 <sup>(64-bit)</sup>

Hence, the question is, why does Chrome forces scrollbar if I use `border-radius` and how can I get the old functionality back where it used to show the scrollbars only if user starts scrolling. This also messes up with dropdown menus I have over pre tag and scrollbars overlap those menus too if I expand them, but that's just out of context for this question.

Comment: On 47 and 49 (canary) the scrollbar always shows for me with or without border radius if it needs to overflow (osx El Capitan)

Comment: This behavior does not appear in Chrome versions `48.0.2564.82 m` or `48.0.2564.97` on Windows 7. My guess is it is probably a visual behavior specific to OSX Yosemite (10.10)

Comment: @DominicTobias Used to work well for me on 47, this issue is specific to 48.

Comment: @TylerH It's surely OSX related.

Comment: I can't reproduce on Yosemite 10.10.5 with `48.0.2564.97` either, but I don't know if it was the 64-bit or 32-bit version of Chrome. The scrollbar showed fine for me on both demos.

Comment: Suspect it's either (a) an issue of the border-radius shrinking the internal width (and height) of the box, causing it to overflow a few pixels earlier. Or (b), the radius prevents the very left edge of the box from being "reached" and the scrollbar is either locked or confused - it thinks it's in the middle somewhere and at the left edge simultaneously. Unsure if this would be a 'frozen scrollbar' or 'infinite actively scrolling 0px left'. Don't have access to a Mac to test.

Comment: Mr. Alien, I'm having this issue as well with Version 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit). I have a MacBook Pro mid-2014 with Yosemite, and I just performed the most recent system update. What I noticed was that it only occurred when the browser window was on an external monitor. If I moved the window to my macbook's screen, the scrollbars disappeared as expected.

Comment: Same issue on Chrome 48.0.2564.97 (64-bit) Mac OS 10.11.3 -- even without border-radius on some divs.  It looks like it might also affect `position: fixed` elements.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `<pre>` tag natively applies the css property "white-space: pre." This preserves the whitespace unless a physical break is used. You should either use a different tag or apply "white-space: normal" to your tag.